# how to initials to gender

Tags: php, laravel-5

please I'm still a beginner, how to give initials to gender. when I import the form "L" then the table will appear "Laki-laki" and "P" Perempuan.

when I import who appears "Perempuan" I try to enter another letter but still the "Perempuan" who appears .

```
$jk = $key->jeniskelamin;
if($jk == "L") { 
    $jeniskelamin = "Laki-laki"; 
} else { 
    $jeniskelamin = "Perempuan"; 
}
```

I change it to if ($ jk = 'L') ... then it will appear "Laki-laki" but when I enter the other letters that appear fixed" Laki-laki "

how do you display it? thank you

Comment: Can you clarify a bit on what you want to achieve? Is it that you have values other than "L" and "P" in `$key->jeniskelamin`, and don't want them to appear as "Perempuan"? (in that case, change your `else` to `elseif ($jk=="P")`)

Comment: the values ​​are "L" and "P", and when I fill in the form with these values ​​it will show "L" is "Laki-laki" and "P" is "Perempuan"

Answer (score 1):

You could try something akin to the following

```
switch( $key->jeniskelamin ){
    case 'L':$jeniskelamin = "Laki-laki"; break;
    case 'P':$jeniskelamin = "Perempuan"; break;
    default:$jeniskelamin = "error"; break;
}
```